# My iPhone 5 synced contacts from my wife's iPhone 5

Tags: ios, contacts

My iPhone 5 (iOS 6.1.2) synced contacts from my wife's iPhone 5 (iOS 7.0.2) and changed many of them (changed names to contacts with similar numbers). She uses my Apple ID, but contacts transfer from her phone to mine. Does anyone know why does it syncs contacts?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same Apple ID for iCloud on both devices then it will sync data like contacts between the two. I would suggest you sign out of iCloud on your device and create a new Apple ID for yourself.

Comment: she's not logged-in in icloud, anyway in that case my contacts should be transferred to her phone, not hers to mine

Comment: @user61956 Do you both sync to iTunes using the same computer or have the same email address which might sync contacts?

Comment: no, we use different mails and computers

Comment: @user61956 In that case I would restore from a backup to get your contacts back and create a new Apple ID for the rest of your phone separate from the one you use with iTunes/AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggesion 1:**

Pardon me for being slightly out of context here, but I'd suggest creating a new Apple ID for her anyway. Apple now has Family Sharing feature, which would allow you to share media and purchases if you need. Though its available in only iOS 8+ (you'll have to upgrade of course) I recently got to upgrade my personal iPhone 4s to iOS 8 and I think its really useful in sorting out such situations with family and kids.

**Suggestion 2:**

I have switched off contacts sync with iTunes completely. Leaving iCloud to be only way the contacts sync, hence reducing the confusion and ambiguity.